# Is "XM_CXSMICON" a misspelling of "SM_CXSMICON" in these MSDN pages?

Tags: winapi, msdn, errata

In the three MSDN articles linked at the bottom of this post, the pre-processor macro `XM_CXSMICON` is mentioned. In context, it is supposed to be the index of the *system metric* that gives the width of a *small* icon in the notification tray or on the balloon-popup of such an icon.

Here is a quote, verbatim:

> **NIIF_LARGE_ICON** (0x00000010)
>   0x00000010. **Windows Vista and later**. The large version of the icon should be used as the icon in the notification balloon. This corresponds to the icon with dimensions SM_CXICON x SM_CYICON. If this flag is not set, the icon with dimensions XM_CXSMICON x SM_CYSMICON is used.

The other three macros from that quote, `SM_CXICON`, `SM_CYICON` and `SM_CYSMICON`, are all defined in `user32.h` as expected but no header file in the Windows API defines `XM_CXSMICON`. Searching the MSDN only returns the hits linked at the end of this post, all of which are related to notify-icons.

With this evidence, I conclude that this is an error and the macro is actually `SM_CXSMICON` which is defined on the line above `SM_CYSMICON` in `user32.h`.

**Can anyone confirm this guess or provide further information?**

The three MSDN articles in question:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352(v=vs.85).aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774428(v=vs.85).aspx
3. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee453691(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have just noticed that I have duplicated a *second* error in the same article! `NIIF_LARGE_ICON` is defined in `shellapi.h` and is `0x00000020`, not `0x00000010` as stated by the tract of text I quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a typo. It should read `SM_CXSMICON` x `SM_CYSMICON`.

Comment: Asked and answered. Thank you.